# Green "Sign Up" button appears in Facebook Like Box

Tags: facebook-iframe, facebook-likebox

When not logged in into Facebook, a green "Sign Up" button sometimes appears on top inside the Facebook Like Box (using the iFrame version). I say sometimes, because it doesn't show up when logged out from FB in my primary browser Chrome (in which i usually use Facebook), but it does show up in FF (so far checked in 8) MSIE (checked in 9).

The main problem i have with the button is that the layout is inconsistent and sometimes appears broken (i have screenshots, but can't post them here because i'm a new user).

So my question is, can this button, or the whole "create and account" header be removed? If not, any suggestions on how i could make this look decent in FF and MSIE?

Thanks
Henrik

Comment: Could you post a screenshot ?
I was not able to get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

This is a cookie issue, since this ugly green "sign up" button appears in any browser that you never used to log in with Facebook.

I've been experiencing the same problem on different browsers, and if you try cleaning up your cookies in your favorite browser then you will see the green button appear again, whatever the browser.

If you use the likebox plugin in iframe mode, this can be avoided by discarding the public profile options, ie setting "stream" and "show_faces" to false.

This is an iframe example that works:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:245px; height:75px;" 
src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fonglesetpaillettes81
&amp;width=245&amp;height=100&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color=%23D4A7AD&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false">
</iframe>
```

Hope this helps.