# Unwanted Facebook sign up button instead if Like button appears

Tags: facebook

This problem has been already discussed on the forum: [Green "Sign Up" button appears in Facebook Like Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455930/green-sign-up-button-appears-in-facebook-like-box) but it was not solved.

I've placed a "like button" on my site and everything worked fine until recently, when it was automatically replaced by a green "sign in" button with the text: "Find us on Facebook. Create an account or Log In to see what your friends like". The button leads to the following url: http://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id=137675572948107&partner_id&placement=likebox_plugin&extra_2=MK

I have no restrictions based on country or age, everyone is allowed to become a fan on my FB page, so I don't see why they have to sign in? It also ruins the look of my site. How to solve this problem? 
**Screenshot below.**
link: http://i1048.photobucket.com/albums/s376/vbbmk/facebook_like_button_error.jpg